# Can drag and drop file URL text, but not actual file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm able to drag a file URL from a NSTableView cell and drop it in any text editor. According to my understanding of Apple's documentation though, when I drop the URL, the file should be copied to the drop location.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {

    //for now putting specific file path in just to get it working
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/Jackh/Desktop/Apple.png";
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType] owner:self];
    [[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] writeToPasteboard:pboard];

    return YES;

}
```

How do I get the file to copy from the filePath to the dropped location? It's just moving filePath as text for now.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I am now using this code

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [self.tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];

}
```

...

```
[self.tableView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, NSFileContentsPboardType, nil]];
```

...

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {

    //for now putting specific file path in just to get it working
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/Jackh/Desktop/Apple.png";
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFileContentsPboardType] owner:nil];
    [pboard writeFileContents:filePath];

}
```

Comment: Is the target editor set to accept Rich Text instead of plain text?  Regardless, it can do whatever it wants with the data that's given; the only way to be sure that it copies the content instead of the path is to provide only the content (i.e. open the file yourself, read the bytes and dump them on the pasteboard with an appropriate type).

Comment: @KevinGrant Thanks Kevin, see my edit above. I can still drag the name out of the NSTableView, but can't drop the file anywhere.

Comment: Do you call `setDraggingSourceOperationMask:forLocal:` anywhere?  I believe you need (e.g. in `awakeFromNib`) something like this: `[tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];` (as well as a separate call for `YES`) to enable both in-table and out-of-table drags.  Also, if you didn't already, change what you pass to `registerForDraggedTypes:` to include the new pasteboard type you're using.

Comment: @KevinGrant I edited my question with the new code. Same thing though. Where exactly should I put the call for `YES`? Do you see any problems with the code above? If not, would you mind spending just a couple minutes to write a working sample for me? I'll obviously upvote you and mark it right, and I'll really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: I got something to work and added it as an Answer below.

Comment: I think the `... forLocal:YES` call can go in the same place as the call for `NO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *force* the green "+" to copy, just use `NSDragOperationCopy` (only) in the operation mask, disallowing other operations; e.g. in `awakeFromNib`:

```
[self.tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationCopy forLocal:NO];
```

Here is the best way I could find to make your example work with the Finder:

```
- (BOOL)
tableView:(NSTableView *)tv
writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)rowIndexes
toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/kevin/Desktop/1.png";
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]
                         owner:nil];
    [pboard setPropertyList:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filePath]
                            forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    return YES;
}
```

Note that Apple recommends using more modern APIs but I have found in cases like this they have a big side effect: they seem to cause files to be copied *twice* because URLs are magically copied in multiple forms.  Having said that, your original URL example didn't work because you should have used `writeObjects:` on the pasteboard instead of asking the URL to `writeToPasteboard:`.  An example with URLs:

```
- (BOOL)
tableView:(NSTableView *)tv
writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)rowIndexes
toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/kevin/Desktop/1.png";
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType]
                         owner:nil];
    [pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
    return YES;
}
```

As I noted in other comments, if your drag is targeting a *document* instead of a file manager such as the Finder then it's better to include the actual data for the file.  Raw data can't be misinterpreted by a document (i.e. the document has to insert the data directly, it can't choose to insert a path string instead).  On the other hand, raw-data drags don't create files in the Finder for some reason so they're useful mainly as something to *add* to the pasteboard as an alternative.

Here is a way to use a UTI to declare the file type and call `NSData` to read a file (I tried this and it works, e.g. I can drag a table view row into a Rich Text document in TextEdit and see an image inserted into the window):

```
- (BOOL)
tableView:(NSTableView *)tv
writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)rowIndexes
toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/kevin/Desktop/1.png";
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.png"]
                         owner:nil];
    [pboard setData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                    forType:@"public.png"];
    return YES;
}
```

(I don't know exactly why your `writeFileContents:` doesn't work but the above does work and is basically the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'm using this code and it still isn't quite working. When I drag the file name around, the green plus does not appear next to the mouse when I am hovering over a Finder window. I'm using a program called `Pasteboard Inspector` and I can see public.png and its NSData in the drag pasteboard, so that is definitely being moved successfully. Do you know why the green plus will not appear though? Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've amended the Answer above to show you how to force a "+" operation, and to produce the best behavior.  Despite being deprecated, `NSFilenamesPboardType` currently has the best behavior when your goal is to force a file copy.  Either way, I've included corrected code for how to make URLs work, and I kept the final example to include the contents of the file in case you decide to use that too.

Comment: It works. You are the best. I honestly can't tell you how much I appreciate this! Thanks.